# Ubuntu doesnt seem to recognize my dvd drive

Tags: mount, dvd

To start off, I have been using Ubuntu for a grand total of 2 1/2 days. I have zero programming experience but I can follow instructions. The reason I switched is so that the potato I run can run faster. I am using Ubuntu Desktop 23.04. Now, said potato is surprisingly fast and decently usable.

But I have a problem. I have been trying to get a DVD drive to be recognized and I have failed abysmally so far.

I have looked at askUbuntu forums, and other places. I know I am supposed to mount the damn thing, but no matter what I do, it doesnt seem to want to mount. I have modified /etc/fstab, I have tried using the Disks application.

I have 2 DVD drives. One is inbuilt into the AIO(/dev/sr0) and doesnt open anymore and I dont use it. The other one is an internal Asus DVD drive(/dev/sr1), that I use with a USB to Sata adapter. The Asus drive worked right out of the box in Windows.

The reason I am doing this is so that I can use MakeMKV and rip some DVD's for my Jellyfin server.

Should I download some packages? Am I missing something? Will an internal dvd drive not work externally?

One more thing, what is the Ctrl-X, C, V equivalents in Ubuntu? I dont know how to copy paste. This can be a reference to my capabilities in Ubuntu. I would greatly appreciate some help

Comment: doing lsblk shows me:

sr1   11:1    1     7G  0 rom

Comment: Then it's recognised your external dvd player. What media player are you using to run a dvd? Also, check that you have the following libraries installed: *libdvdcss*, *libdvdnav* and *libdvdread*.